# TemplatedParent not working in MultiBinding: getting "UnsetValue" everytime

Tags: wpf, multibinding, wpf-style

I am trying to bind visibility of a styled control to the condition that its tag is equal to the selected index of a TabControl.

I use `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` but it's not being set, and I suspect it's because I am not setting `Template` property in Style.

Here is my code:

```
    <Grid x:Name="Telas" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <vw:TagIsIndexBooleanConverter x:Key="TagIsIndexBooleanConverter"/>
            <Style x:Key="SelectedIndexVisibleStyle" TargetType="UserControl">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TagIsIndexBooleanConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                <Binding Path="SelectedIndex" ElementName="menu"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <vw:TelaColetaView
            x:Name="telaColeta"
            DataContext="{Binding TelaColetaVM}"
            Style="{StaticResource SelectedIndexVisibleStyle}"
            Tag="0"/>

        <vw:TelaPacientesView
            x:Name="telaPacientes"
            DataContext="{Binding TelaPacientesVM}"
            Style="{StaticResource SelectedIndexVisibleStyle}"
            Tag="1"/>

        <vw:TelaConfiguraçõesView
            x:Name="telaConfigurações"
            DataContext="{Binding TelaConfiguraçõesVM}"
            Style="{StaticResource SelectedIndexVisibleStyle}"
            Tag="4"/>

    </Grid>
```

And converter:

```
public class TagIsIndexBooleanConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Any(v => v == null || v == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        var tag = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
        var index = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
        var result = tag == index;
        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `TemplatedParent` in this case because there isn't one; that's meant to used inside a `ControlTemplate` to specify that the source for the binding is the control that you're applying the template to.

```
<Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
```

But this isn't inside a `ControlTemplate`. Instead, `Tag` is just a property of the thing you're styling. Ordinarily you'd do a trigger like this for `Tag`:

```
<Trigger Property="Tag" Value="0">
```

...but you need a multibinding to get the `SelectedIndex` from `menu`, and it's got to be a `MultiDataBinding` because you need to specify `ElementName`.

So you need a binding. To bind to one of your own properties instead of a property of your `DataContext`, you bind with a `RelativeSource` of `Self`:

```
<Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
```

OP also found he had to set the `TargetType` of the `Style` to `"UserControl"`, for the `Tag` binding to work.

Comment: To add a bit to this great answer, it seems that setting the `TargetType=UserControl` in the Style was necessary for the `<Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>` to work.

Comment: @heltonbiker Added that, and zapped my comments.